# Effective Android app for ad blocking

Tags: android, ad-blocker

I'm looking for a free and effective app (without ads) to block ads in android.

I've tried a couple (don't ask me which) but none of them were really effective.

Comment: Is your device rooted? If not, do you need to use a VPN for some purpose (as with non-root solutions, that wouldn't work together)? For a list of useful ad-blockers, see [here]([Ad-Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker)) on my site. I use AdAway (rooted device); I cannot tell about effectivity of non-rooted solutions.

Comment: Is this for ad when browsing websites or also include in-game ads? For in-game ads, if it is an online game, turn off the internet works for me. I also want to know if any mobile browser adblocker exists. This is the reason I prefer browsing in PC rather than in mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about web browsing, I've been using Firefox with [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/ublock-origin/). It works like a charm.

My first goal was to have an ad-free YouTube, which I think is impossible to have with the official app, but the user experience in Firefox is really good.

On a related note, I have not been able to reproduce this on my iPad, because the [iOS version of Firefox does not support addons](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-ons-firefox-ios).

I've been hearing too about the web browser [Brave](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser&hl=en_US) which includes an ad-blocker, though I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You should try AdAway if your device is rooted: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190753

The app modifies the device's hosts file so ads get blocked on system level, you don't have to do it per app.

It's free and [open source](https://github.com/AdAway/AdAway) so you have nothing to lose (or fear).

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate partial solution:**
Disable internet access to apps that don't need internet for your use. Settings--> Apps--> Permissions, now disable both wireless and data access to those apps. Only give permissions to browsers, messengers .. that must need internet access.

It's a long manual work but this I found most effective so far.

**Browser Solution:**
Use firefox on your android with "Adblock Plus" add-ons. Open firefox-->Options-->Add-ons-->add "Adblock Plus"

Answer (score 1):

The most effective non rooted ad blocking solution is [blokada](https://blokada.org/index.html). It runs a vpn and blocks all the ad request using dns blocking. It blocks ads across all apps.

You can download it from its website or from f-droid.